# ASP.NET - IIS 7 - DotNetNuke - How do I force browsers to reload the site's CSS?

Tags: asp.net, css, iis, caching, dotnetnuke

I have run into the problem where my css files are being cached in browsers. This is a fairly common problem, and a common solution is to simple add a version number in the url to the css file. Example: MyCSS.css?ver=1.12

However, I'm using a custom skin for DotNetNuke which forces the usage of the file: skin.css

I don't have a way to point browsers to skin.css?ver=1.12 (or at least I'm not aware of a way)

Are there any tricks I can play with IIS, DNN, or ASP.NET (default.aspx file for DNN perhaps?) to force clients to reload CSS?

Comment: An oldie, but you should do skin.css/?v1.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the IIS Manager, right-click on the file and select Properties. Go to the HTTP Headers tab, tick Enable Content Expiration and set a very low value on your new file.

Comment: Looks like that domain got snatched up by some redirect marketing outfit. I know it's old but what is it with all things DNN and expired websites and broken links?

Answer (score 0):

When the skin is created "correctly" the skin.css file should (in DNN 6+ I think) include a version QS parameter when it's loaded.
The version number is upped when you install a new skin version or you can do this through Host > Host (application) settings > Advanced settings > Client Resource Management > [Increment Version]